# Regular expression that accepts alphanumeric , non consecutive dash and non consecutive white space

Tags: regex

Can anyone help me create a regular expression that accepts alphanumeric (numbers and letters only) and dashes and white spaces.

It shouldn't accept consecutive dashes and consecutive white spaces. or a dash followed by a white space and vice versa.
It should always begin and end with alphanumeric characters as well.

Thank you so much. Any help would be very much appreciated. (^-^)v

```
'Abcde' , '324 3a-32' : valid

'-' , '324 3a - 32' , '-2323  d-', 'z- -a' : invalid
```

---

Thanks guys for all your help.  v(",)\

Comment: ASCII-, or Unicode letters? What programming language are you working with?

Comment: Javascript. I used the regex Alan Moore posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

When the first `[A-Za-z0-9]+` runs out of letters and digits, the `[\s-]` inside the group tries to match a hyphen or a whitespace character.  If it succeeds, the second `[A-Za-z0-9]+` tries to match some more alphanumerics.  And the group gets repeated as many times as necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This one fits the requirements best. Thank you so much. This has been very helpful.  o(^-^)v

Comment: My pleasure.  If this answer has solved your problem, please mark it as accepted (it's that green check-mark icon next to the answer).

Comment: how to exclude spaces?

Comment: as I do have spaces and dashes and i do like space around dashes (optional) my regex is: ^[A-Za-z0-9]+((\s|\s?-\s?)[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$ - this allows single spaces, dashes (which might have space before and after). similarly allow space, comma foll. by space is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([ \t-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

Comment: This seems to match even if there's a - on the end (testing with Perl)

Comment: @Cfreak, no, that isn't correct. The matched string always starts- and ends with a char from the class: `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: This regex looks good, but the `?` after the `[ \t-]` has no business being there.  That part has to match exactly one character each time it's applied; it's not optional.

Answer (score 1):

An ASCII answer

```
^(?!.*[- ]{2})(?!^[- ])(?!.*[- ]$)[A-Za-z0-9- ]+$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u615)

`^` Matches the start of the string

`$` Matches the end of the string

`[A-Za-z0-9- ]+` Matches the characters you want, at least one

The negative lookaheads

`(?!.*[- ]{2})` ensures that there are not - or space in a row

`(?!^[- ])(?!.*[- ]$)` those two ensures that it does not start and not end with these characters.

For an unicode answer you should specify the language you are using

for some you can use `\p{L}` [See here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html) to describe a unicode code point that has the property "letter".

Comment: Although correct, a pattern without all the look-arounds (which is easily constructed) is preferred, IMO.

Comment: You forgot the backslash before `p{L}`.

Answer (score -2):

```
/[\da-z]+[ -]?([\da-z][ -]?)*[\da-z]/i
```

Comment: That would reject a single letter, which should be valid by the OP's definition.

Comment: "It should always begin and end with alphanumeric characters". I am seeing a plural, which makes the difference. Consider this in contradiction to the sentence "It should always begin and end with an alphanumeric character" which would also fit for a single character.